# Solving special boolean equation set

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, boolean-algebra

I have boolean equation sets that look like this (where ^ means xor):

> eq 1: x1^x3^x5^x6^x9^x10^x11^x13^x17^x18 = 0
>
> eq 2: 1^x1^x3^x10^x12^x17 = 0
>
> eq 3: 1^x2^x3^x5^x8^x10^x14^x16 = 0
>
> eq 4: 1^x4^x5^x6^x7^x8^x10^x16^x17 = 0
>
> eq 5: x2^x5^x8^x11^x13^x14^x17^x18 = 0

(This example has 18 vars and 5 equations, but imagine a thousand variables with a hundred equations).

I can easily find solutions for this by successive subtitutions, but is there any way to quickly generate solution(s) **with the least number of variables set to true** ?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  It can be reformulated as a minimal covering problem, if we treat the boolean unknowns as if they were "sets" (containing the "equation" items in which they appear).

Comment: Denoting "xor" by ^ is not common. Typically, ^ denotes "and," instead.

Comment: I think this can be solved using Gaussian elimination over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: Ah, I used ^ as xor because of my C background, I am not very familiar with latex formatting.

Answer (score 1):

We can phrase the problem as follows:

> Given $M \in \mathbb{F}_2^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{F}_2^m$ with $n>m$, find the solution $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ to $Mx=b$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is minimized.

That is, this may be regarded as a "linear programming" problem, of sorts.  Below is my initial attempt at a solution, which was not particularly fruitful.

---

We can write this particular system as the matrix equality
$$
M\,x = b
$$
Where $M$ is the matrix of coefficients (either $1$ or $0$) of $x_1,\dots,x_{18}$, $x = \pmatrix{x_1&\dots&x_{18}}^T$, and $b = \pmatrix{0&1&1&1&0}^T$ (corresponding to whether the equation contains a "`1^`"). With row reduction, we can determine how many of $x_1,\dots,x_{18}$ are "free variables", i.e. variables that may be arbitrarily set to true or false.  The key here is to note that we define multiplication and addition over these elements/coefficients in $\{0,1\}$ as follows:
$$
a+b = a\text{ XOR } b\\
a\cdot b = a \text{ AND } b
$$
This is the definition of [$\mathbb{F}_2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29).

---

Let's take an example.  Suppose we have the system

```
x1 ^ x2 ^ x3 == 0
x2 ^ x3 ^ x4 == 1
x3 ^ x4 ^ x5 == 1
```

We can write this as
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&1}
\pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_5} =
\pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1}
$$
We can now [row reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_reduction) the augmented matrix $(M\mid b)$ to get
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&1&1}
\implies\\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$ 
That is, the system may be rewritten as

```
x1     ^     x4       == 1
    x2 ^           x5 == 0
         x3 ^ x4 ^ x5 == 1
```

So that $x_4,x_5$ may be freely chosen, and the values of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ may be solved for as

```
x1 == 1 ^ x4
x2 == x5
x3 == 1^x4^x5
```

Hope that makes sense.

---

NOTE: this may not be as useful for the particular problem as I originally thought.

Comment: Indeed, row reduce is fine to find a solution, but doesn't help much to find a solution with the least number of variables set to true... which gets impossible to brute-force as the number of variables get big.

Comment: I realized that after typing all this up.  I think what you're looking for is an extension of the concept of a Moore-Penrose inverse to matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  I have a hunch that any solution to $M^TM x = M^T b$ will be a solution that minimizes the number of non-zero elements, which would mean that any solution to the above will do.  I'm not sure though.

Comment: Thanks for properly rephrasing the problem and for the tentative solution, much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are right, according to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_pseudoinverse):

For linear systems  with non-unique solutions (such as under-determined systems), the pseudoinverse may be used to construct the solution of minimum Euclidean norm  among all solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the wikipedia page is talking about matrices with real/complex entries, while I'm talking about matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$.  If you solve the system using the multiplication rules of $\mathbb{F}_2$, I'm not sure that you keep the Euclidean norm minimization property. If you solve the system using the normal multiplication rules of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, you're not guaranteed to get a solution consisting of $1$s and $0$s.

Comment: Looking at the proof for the Euclidean norm minimum ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore–Penrose_pseudoinverse#Minimum-norm_solution_to_a_linear_system ), I'm not sure which part may not hold in GF(2), but this is beyond my skills. Perhaps I should just implement the solver, test on a few thousands random cases I can also brute-force and then compare ?

Comment: That should do it. Try it for a small number first.